# How can I combine range() functions

Tags: python, python-2.x

For some code I'm writing, I need to iterate from 1-30 skipping 6. What I tried naively is

```
a = range(1,6)
b = range(7,31)

for i in a+b:
    print i
```

Is there a way to do it more efficiently?

Comment: What you have posted works. What exactly are you asking? Is there a way to do it 'better'?

Comment: The above works in python2, but not python3

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In python 2 you are not combining "range functions"; these are just lists. Your example works just well. But range always creates a full list in memory, so a better way if only needed in for loop could be to to use a generator expression and xrange:

```
range_with_holes = (j for j in xrange(1, 31) if j != 6)

for i in range_with_holes:
    ....
```

In generator expression the if part can contain a complex logic on which numbers to skip.

Another way to combine iterables is to use the `itertools.chain`:

```
range_with_holes = itertools.chain(xrange(1, 6), xrange(7, 31))
```

Or just skip the unwanted index

```
for i in range(1, 31):
    if i == 6:
        continue

    ...
```

Answer (score 24):

Use [`itertools.chain`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain):

```
import itertools

a = range(1,6)
b = range(7,31)

for i in itertools.chain(a, b):
    print i
```

Or tricky flattening generator expressions:

```
a = range(1,6)
b = range(7,31)
for i in (x for y in (a, b) for x in y):
    print i
```

Or skipping in a generator expression:

```
skips = set((6,))
for i in (x for x in range(1, 31) if x not in skips):
    print i
```

Any of these will work for any iterable(s), not just `range`s in Python 3 or `lists`s in Python 2.

Answer (score 2):

One option would be to use a skip list, and check against that, with something like:

```
skips = [6, 42]
for i in range(1,31):
   if i in skips:
      continue
   print i
```

Answer (score 0):

I use list conversion:

```
>>> list(range(10,13)) + list(range(1,5))
[10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: You must `set()` your resulting list to make your solution work correctly.