# Using multiple ranges with the for-loop in PYTHON

Tags: python, range

I don't understand of using the multiple ranges in the for-loop as follows.

```
for n in range(1,21) + range(30,100,10):
   # do something
```

I googled but still not find out. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What exactly confuses you?

Comment: The term `range(a,b) + range(c,d,e)` makes me confused.

Comment: @TungLe if `range(1,21) + range(30,100,10)` confuses you then try `print range(1,21) + range(30,100,10)` and see what it gives you, that would probably clear up your confusion without the need to ask here.

Comment: also googling [python add range together](https://www.google.ca/webhp?hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiQiqrs-sjNAhXCOiYKHVQwBREQPAgD#hl=en&q=python+add+range+together) turned up [How can I combine range() functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18317913/how-can-i-combine-range-functions) as the fourth top hit, the first sentence of the [accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18317975/5827215) is "In python 2 you are not combining "range functions"; these are just lists."

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen: I got it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each range expression returns a list: `range(1,21)` returns `[1,2,...,20]`, and `range(30,100,10)` returns `[30,40,...,90]`. The `+` operator concatenates the two lists, so `range(1,21) + range(30,100,10)` evaluates to `[1,2,...,20,30,40,...,90]`.

Answer (score 7):

In *Python 2.7*, you can add `range`s because the result of calling `range(something)` [is a list](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html?highlight=range#range), and lists [can be added](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq) to produce a new list:

```
>>> range(5)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]

>>> range(8,12)
[8, 9, 10, 11]

>>> range(5) + range(8,12)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 8, 9, 10, 11]
```

But in *Python 3.5* you can't do this as the `range` type represents an *immutable sequence* of numbers. Check [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-range) for more information.

Comment: You can use `itertools.chain()` in Python 3.